# Multiple Tables Group and substract sum of columns using linq sql

Tags: linq

Here i have two tables

Table One

```
+---------------+----------+------------+
| Raw Material  |  Size    |  Qty       | 
+---------------+----------+------------+
|  A            |  1       |  5         |
|  A            |  2       |  2         |
|  A            |  1       |  2         |
|  B            |  0       |  5         |
|  B            |  0       |  1         |
+---------------+----------+------------+
```

Table Two

```
+---------------+----------+------------+
| Raw Material  |  Size    |  Qty       |
+---------------+----------+------------+
|  A            |  1       |  2         |
|  A            |  2       |  1         |
|  A            |  1       |  1         |
+---------------+----------+------------+
```

I want out put like

```
+---------------+----------+------------+
| Raw Material  |  Size    |  Qty       |
+---------------+----------+------------+
|  A            |  1       |  4         |
|  A            |  2       |  1         |
|  B            |  0       |  6         |
+---------------+----------+------------+
```

Want to get substract first two tables sum of **qty** by grouping **Rawmaterial and Size**

Comment: i think there is no direct way you have to write code for this...Grouping you can do on both table and than you need write your cutom logic for substract part ...

Comment: @Pranay Rana OK I tried, but how to get Rawmaterial  and size after group table

Comment: @Andrea Dusza Yes I made mistake sorry

Comment: you can check grouping query in my answer

Comment: Wait a moment, you guys want something. So why don't you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the job

```
var result = tableA.Select(e => new { Item = e, Factor = 1 })
    .Concat(tableB.Select(e => new { Item = e, Factor = -1 }))
    .GroupBy(e => new { e.Item.RawMaterial, e.Item.Size }, (key, elements) => new
    { 
        RawMaterial = key.RawMaterial,
        Size = key.Size,
        Qty = elements.Sum(e => e.Item.Qty * e.Factor)
    }).ToList();
```

First we create a union of the two tables using `Concat`, including the information which one is additive (in `Factor` field), and then just do the normal grouping.

If you want the result to be `List<YourTableElementType>`, just replace the final anonymous type projection (`new { ... }`) with `new YourTableElementType { ... }`.

Comment: Really elegant solution with the factor to avoid having to do subtraction and joins. I was about to post another more complicated solution, but I rest my case.